# Does it exist an example application provided by lagom

Tags: lagom

I found lagom is a cqrs and es framework for microservice. But i don't found an example application to kick off quickly.I wonder if it is on plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find the Chirper Activator template useful. You'll find it here: http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/lagom-java-chirper

From the description:

> This project demonstrates how to build a twitter-like application,
>   with a few microservices, in Java. For a step by step guide of the
>   project watch the screencasts:
>
> - Introduction to Lagom and its Service API.
> - Development Setup. Managing
> - Data Persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few other (simple) examples.

Service without persistence
https://github.com/orefalo/lagom-snowflake

Service with persistence
https://github.com/orefalo/lagom-sample-bank